# Someone submitted my code as their code in an assignment; what should I do now?

Tags: ethics, plagiarism, cheating

I am second year student; one of my friends stole my code and then applied for an extension. I submitted my file on the deadline day and they submitted 10 days later using the same file as mine. Two days earlier someone told me they submitted my file. My mental health going down; what should I do now?

Comment: I am not sure why you are worried. The other student submitted the same code 10 days after you did. Your prof should be able to figure out what happened.

Comment: What do you mean by "stole"? Did they break into your notebook and took the code, or did you share it with them willingly? How close are you with this friend? Naturally, if they are indeed your friend, the best way would be to just convince them to admit that they copied your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Talk to the professor. Assure them that you wrote the code you submitted and that you didn't share it with anyone else. Say that you were told someone stole the code from you. Don't say who. You don't need to (and should not) accuse anyone.

Find better "friends".